# id.text() of jquery ignoring more than 1 white space in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a span with id SOMEID.When I am accessing its text value using folloing code it is breaking in IE8 and IE7 only.How to fix it.

`$("#DocumentPath").text()`. If DocumentPath contain name like `My   doc.txt` it is not working. Note here there is 3 white space between My and doc.

Answer (score 2):

You very vague problem description "code it is breaking" can make us only guess, but note the following: IE treats whitespaces in the markup differently than other browsers.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> (Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.)
>
> The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.
>
> As of jQuery 1.4, the .text() method returns the value of text and CDATA nodes as well as element nodes.

Thus said, it may be more appropriate for you, to use the `html()` method.

Comment: If it's a result of IE's HTML parser, then I doubt using `.html()` will help. I would imagine IE is removing superfluous spaces while parsing the document. I'm checking right now...

Comment: ...confirmed, the `.html()` and `.innerHTML` give the same compressed result as `.text()` in IE8.

Comment: @user1689607 I meant `html()` might give a more consistent result across the browsers.

Comment: No, .text(), .html() ,. innerhtml() all give same result.

Comment: @user1802046 there is no such thing as `innerhtml()` - it's a native browserthing and called `innerHTML` - `text()` and `html()` are jQuery methods. `text()` gives the combined text of all matched elements and `html()` gives you the content of the first matched element. You only get a similar result by coincidence. By default, in html multiple whitespaces get combined into 1 whitespace, that's why IE8- returns you only one whitespace. Perhaps declaring `white-space:pre-wrap;` on your element could help. (Or `white-space:pre;` on IE7 since `pre-wrap` is not supported here.)

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$("#DocumentPath").html()
```

That said you say your span has an id SOMEID?! If it's id is SOMEID it should be:

```
$("#SOMEID").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try another approach, on jQuery's docs they recommend call `.eval()` function to retrieve a value instead of `.text()` check their doc:http://api.jquery.com/text/

So the code snippet could be:

```
$("#DocumentPath").eval()
```

Regards

:)